# Getting Theano to use the GPU and all CPU cores (at the same time)

Tags: cuda, theano

I managed to get Theano working with either GPU or multicore CPU on Ubuntu 14.04 by following [this tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html).

First I got multicore working (I could verify that in System Monitor).
Then, after adding the config below to .theanorc, I got GPU working:

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatX = float32
```

I verified it by running the test from the tutorial and checking the execution times, and also by the log message when running my program:

> "Using gpu device 0: GeForce GT 525M"

But as soon as GPU started working I wouldn't see multicore in System Monitor anymore. It uses just one core at 100% like before.

How can I use both? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't fully utilize both multicore and GPU at the same time. 
Maybe this can be impoved in the future.